# C# cmd command does not work on Windows 7

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-7, windows-10, sqlcmd

I tried to use command line to avoid some issue using Windows 7 and LocalDB 2016.
Here is the code:

```
Process cmd = new Process();

ProcessStartInfo infocmd = new ProcessStartInfo();
// infocmd.CreateNoWindow = true; (using when code is ok for win 7)
infocmd.Verb = "runas";
infocmd.FileName = "cmd";
infocmd.RedirectStandardInput = true;
infocmd.UseShellExecute = false;

cmd.StartInfo = infocmd;
cmd.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = cmd.StandardInput)
{
    sw.WriteLine("sqllocaldb stop localedb");
    sw.WriteLine("sqllocaldb delete localedb");
    sw.WriteLine("sqllocaldb create localedb");
    sw.WriteLine("sqllocaldb start localedb");
}

cmd.WaitForExit();
```

All works fine in Windows 10 (OS that I use to develop) but when I move the program to Windows 7, `cmd.exe` starts, but it closes a few millisecond later (with NO error and NO exception) and `localedb` instance is not being created.

If manually type the code in `sw.WriteLine` on Windows 7, it works fine, so there is no problems with LocalDB 2016.

There is any ways to fix this?

There is any part of code to edit to work with Windows 7 (and Windows 10 too)?

Comment: Have you tried to write any trace log?

Comment: this is unclear. What you want to do with localdb? You mean local database system provided by Micorsoft?:)

Comment: @kennyzx No I don't, sorry but can I write trace log with this?

Comment: By trace log, I mean writing a message after each line so you can be clear if some lines are skipped during execution, you can write the messages to a file.

Comment: @P.K. Sorry if this is unclear. I mean SQL LocalDB. All this code is to avoid some problems that i found with SQL LocalDB 2016 on Windows 7. By code I just want stop an instance, delete that istance, create a new one with the same name (localEdb) then start last created.

Comment: @kennyzx- Ok thanks, but I don't know how to do a tracelog, sorry

Comment: @kennyzx, whew I add " (StreamReader reader = md.StandardOutput) { string result = reader.ReadToEnd();MessageBox.Show(result);}" Now all work on Win 7, why?? I don't change any other part of code. If I remove this part of code it come back to not working.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just execute `sqllocaldb` directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

Put
`cmd.ReadKey();`

at the end of your code. It will wait for a key before closing the cmd console.

**EDIT**

Replace cmd with Console ( ctrl + H in Visual Studio to Find and Replace All)

Works on Windows 7 and higher.